# Parametrized depth query in xpath

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to select elements `<BBB>` who have in their descendants at least 2 more elements of the same type at different depths.
I found it possible with:

```
//BBB//BBB//BBB
```

but if i want to change the depth of my query I have to write:

```
//BBB//BBB//BBB//BBB
or
//BBB//BBB
```

Is it possible specify the depth of my query with a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//BBB[ancestor::BBB[$pN]]
```

Where `$pN` should be substituted with the desired number of `BBB` descendants at different depths.

Answer (score 5):

You can search for elements that have at least two/three/... ancestors of a type, e.g.:

```
//*[count(ancestor::BBB) >= 2]
```