# HtmlAgilityPack select nodes on first level

Tags: html-agility-pack

Consider the following HTML

```html
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      <tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td>5</td>
</tr>
```

What I want here is to take all `<td>` elements which are direct descendants to the main `<tr>` row.
Which means, I want to take `1, 2 and 5`.

The code I am using

```
gridRow.Descendants("td")
```

will return all `<td>` elements below the main `<tr>` node.

Does HtmlAgilityPack provide the functionality to get first level descendants (because I can't find such method) ?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13187588/736079

Comment: Probably a solution, but I am trying to avoid XPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HtmlNode.Elements("child_name")` is exactly what you are looking for :

```cs
gridRow.Elements("td")
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think this will work:

```
 gridRow.Descendants("td").Where(x => x.ParentNode == gridRow)
```

This will return all `<td>` elements, whose direct parent is the main `<tr>` element.